# Use CSS rotate3d on already rotated div

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have problem with axis of already rotated div.

Right now the diamond rotates within sides and I want to rotate by top center of it.

Here's an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/DtQd8/

**HTML**

```
<div class="diamond">
    <div class="diamondIn">
        <div class="front"></div>
        <div class="back"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.diamond
{
height: 150px;
width: 150px;
-webkit-perspective: 1000;
-moz-perspective: 1000;
perspective: 1000;
transform: rotate(-45deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
-o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
position: absolute;
}

.diamondIn
{
height: 150px;
width: 150px;
-webkit-transition: 0.6s;
-moz-transition: 0.6s;
transition: 0.6s;
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
transform-style: preserve-3d;
position: relative;
float: left;
}

.diamondIn:hover
{
-webkit-transform: rotate3d(0,1,0,180deg);
-moz-transform: rotate3d(0,1,0,180deg);
transform: rotate3d(0,1,0,180deg);
}

.diamondIn .front,
.diamondIn .back
{
top: 0;
left: 0;
height: 150px;
width: 150px;
background: #fff;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
backface-visibility: hidden;
position: absolute;
}

.diamondIn .front
{
z-index: 2;
background: #00ff00;
}

.diamondIn .back
{
-webkit-transform: rotate3d(0,1,0,180deg);
-moz-transform: rotate3d(0,1,0,180deg);
transform: rotate3d(0,1,0,180deg);
background: #ff0000;
}
```

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made small edits to your CSS. I have changed the "Transform" property to +45 degree. Along with this also changed the coordinates for 3D. Below is the updated code:

```
.diamond
{
height: 150px;
width: 150px;
-webkit-perspective: 1000;
-moz-perspective: 1000;
perspective: 1000;
transform: rotate(45deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
-o-transform: rotate(45deg);
position: absolute;
}

.diamondIn
{
height: 150px;
width: 150px;
-webkit-transition: 0.6s;
-moz-transition: 0.6s;
transition: 0.6s;
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
transform-style: preserve-3d;
position: relative;
float: left;
}

.diamondIn:hover
{
-webkit-transform: rotate3d(150,150,0,180deg);
-moz-transform: rotate3d(150,150,0,180deg);
transform: rotate3d(150,150,0,180deg);
}

.diamondIn .front,
.diamondIn .back
{
top: 0;
left: 0;
height: 150px;
width: 150px;
background: #fff;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
backface-visibility: hidden;
position: absolute;
}

.diamondIn .front
{
z-index: 2;
background: #00ff00;
}
.diamondIn .back
{
-webkit-transform: rotate3d(150,150,0,180deg);
-moz-transform: rotate3d(150,150,0,180deg);
transform: rotate3d(150,150,0,180deg);
background: #ff0000;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The transformation of the outer div changes the coordinate system for inner divs (good explanation [here](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/understanding-the-css-transforms-matrix/#coordinates)). That's why the inner divs rotate around the axis that are already rotated themselves.

Wouldn't it be better/easier to apply the 'static' transformation to the inner divs and dynamically rotate the whole construction, in non-transformed coordinates?

I edited your JSFiddle a bit, trying to explain all the transformations happening there in the comments: [jsfiddle.net/DtQd8/2/](http://goo.gl/MXkpr2). Have I guessed the task? :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to add **left** , **top** and **margin-left**

```
.diamond
{
height: 150px;
width: 150px;
-webkit-perspective: 1000;
-moz-perspective: 1000;
perspective: 1000;
transform: rotate(-45deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
-o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
position: absolute;
top:40px;
left:50%;
margin-left:-75px;
}
```

demo http://jsfiddle.net/DtQd8/1/

Comment: I have no idea how to use it on my example... I don't understand it.

Comment: then try left and top

Comment: Hmm, maybe I have explained wrong. What I meant to write is that I want to rotate diamond from left corner to right corner, not from left bottom edge to right top edge.